# Attach attribute to every JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

If I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "Person1": {
        "name": "Jon",
        "value1": 4,
        "value2": 2
    },
    "Person2": {
        "name": "Jane",
        "value1": 12,
        "value2": 3
    },
}
```

I would like to attach a new attribute to every single object in the JSON file that is equal to value1/value2. For example, this new "value3" would be 2 for the first object and 4 for the second object. The end result should look something like this:

```
{
    "Person1": {
        "name": "Jon",
        "value1": 4,
        "value2": 2,
        "value3": 2
    },
    "Person2": {
        "name": "Jane",
        "value1": 12,
        "value2": 3,
        "value3": 4
    },
}
```

This has to be done on a mass scale so I can't just enter everything manually. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Object.values

```js
dx={
  "Person1": {
      "name": "Jon",
      "value1": 4,
      "value2": 2
  },
  "Person2": {
      "name": "Jane",
      "value1": 12,
      "value2": 3
  },
}
Object.values(dx).forEach(x=>{
  x["value3"]=x.value1/x.value2
})
console.log(dx)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to update every value.

```js
const obj = {
    "Person1": {
        "name": "Jon",
        "value1": 4,
        "value2": 2
    },
    "Person2": {
        "name": "Jane",
        "value1": 12,
        "value2": 3
    },
};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>obj[key].value3 = obj[key].value1/obj[key].value2);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the outer brackets should be `[...]`, since it is an array.

To your problem: You can just run through all elements - either by using `arr.forEach()` or a for-loop and setting the value.

To set the value just use `elem['value3'] = elem['value1'] / elem['value2']`. `elem` being the current element.

You have to ensure, that both values are always present and `value2` is never 0. You would have to expand the code if that would be the case.

Comment: It's not an Array, it's an Object, with keys `"Person1"`, `"Person2"`

Comment: Oh, nevermind.. then use Object.keys() to access all elements...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mutate the original data, you can use [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const data = {Person1:{name:"Jon",value1:4,value2:2},Person2:{name:"Jane",value1:12,value2:3}};

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data)
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, { ...v, value3: v.value1 / v.value2 }])
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Object.entries() and a forEach loop to mutate original

```js
const o = {Person1:{name:"Jon",value1:4,value2:2},Person2:{name:"Jane",value1:12,value2:3}};

Object.entries(o).forEach(([k,{value1:v1,value2:v2}])  => o[k].value3 = v1/v2)

console.log(o)
```